# How to check a String value to know in its's contain the specific letter in java?

Tags: java

I want to check a String Value to know if it contains an exact match, not just some characters.

I'm searching in computer

```
String computer = ("monitor" + "\n" + "case" + "\n" + "mouse" + "\n" + "hard" + "\n" + "VGA" + "CPU");
```

for the exact match myLetter:

```
String myLetter = "monitor";
```

As opposed to just a partial match i.e. in the above case "mo", this should return false.

```
boolean state = computer.contains("mo"); 
boolean state = computer.contains(myLetter);
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to check if any of the letters in `myLetter` exists in `computer`?

Comment: yes, i wanna check ant of the letters not some of them.

Comment: How about not using a bad data structure like a `String` here? Use a collection (like [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and search with [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) to search for your _whole_ words. If you need a String, for example to display it somewhere, then you can still build it very easily.

Comment: Okay Tom. Your comment is really an answer and a much better one than the ones below.

Comment: Personally (depending on requirements) I'd use a SQLite database and its FTS ability. This question was originally tagged with an Android tag and using SQLite with FTS is standard for searches and would fit the OP's question perfectly for an Android app.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use word boundaries like so:

```
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\b" + myLetter +"\\b.*");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(computer);
     boolean b = m.find();

     System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to find the whole word "monitor", but not its parts, like "mo". You can do it with regular expression patterns:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + myLetter + "\\b");
boolean state = pattern.matcher(computer).find();
```

"\b" in regular expression means that you need to match the word boundary here. So this will not match:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bmo\\b");
boolean state = pattern.matcher(computer).find();
```

But this will match:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bmonitor\\b");
boolean state = pattern.matcher(computer).find();
```

Comment: thank you @Sergey Petunin, this is work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
boolean isExist = computer.indexOf("mo") != -1;
```

The `indexOf()` will return -1 if the String doesn't exist and 0 or greater if it does which is the index which the parameter actually starts.

Comment: thank u but this is wrong, because i don't wanna find "mo" or "se", i wanna find all the words not some word of it.

Comment: so just put inside the parameter what you need, anyway, this is the best way to check if some string exists in another string, or either consider using regex instead

Answer (score 1):

Is myletter determined? It can be packaged into a method like this:

```
    public boolean isContain(String s,String m){
       String myLetter = "monitor";
       if(myLetter.equals(s)){
            return m.contains(s);
       }
       return false;
   }
```

Use it:

```
isContain("mo",computer);
```

Comment: no this is wrong too, i don't wanna if i search "mo" or "se" the true returned.